# Inner join operation on two tables with conditions produces different results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have Two Tables with the following structure:

### **Table1:TASK_MASTER**

```
TASK_ID |   TASK_CREATOR_ID  |   TASK_ASSIGNEE_ID  |   CREATED_DATE    
--------+--------------------+---------------------+------------------------
 1             1                      2                2014-09-24 12:00:00
 2             2                      1                2014-09-25 12:00:00
```

### **Table2:USER_MASTER**

```
USER_ID       NAME         PHONE_NUMBER
------------------------------------------
  1          ABHISEK       9804XXXXXX
  2          SMITH         9038XXXXXX
```

I need the name of `TASK CREATOR (TASK_CREATOR_ID)` and the name of `TASK_ASSIGNEE(TASK_ASSIGNEE_ID)` from `TASK_MASTER` and `USER_MASTER)`

I tried this code:

```
select TM.TASK_ASSIGNEE,TM.TASK_CREATOR,
TM.CREATED_DATE,UM.FIRST_NAME,UM.FIRST_NAME,UM.PHONE_NUMBER
FROM TASK_MASTER TM
INNER JOIN USER_MASTER UM 
ON TM.TASK_ASSIGNEE_ID=UM.USER_ID  
AND TM.TASK_CREATOR_ID=UM.USER_ID 
where TASK_ID='1'
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: But why are you shouting?

Answer (score 1):

You need two joins for this:

```
select TM.TASK_ASSIGNEE, TM.TASK_CREATOR, TM.CREATED_DATE,
       UMA.FIRST_NAME,  UMA.FIRST_NAME, UMA.PHONE_NUMBER,
       UMC.FIRST_NAME,  UMC.FIRST_NAME, UMC.PHONE_NUMBER,
FROM TASK_MASTER TM LEFT JOIN
     USER_MASTER UMA
     ON TM.TASK_ASSIGNEE_ID = UMA.USER_ID LEFT JOIN
     USER_MASTER UMC
     ON TM.TASK_CREATOR_ID = UMC.USER_ID 
where TM.TASK_ID = '1';
```

I also switched the joins to `Left Join`s.  In case there are no matches on one of the rows, the task will still appear.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do two joins one for the creator and one for the Assignee. Both the id:s will not match. Like this:

```
select 
    TM.TASK_ASSIGNEE,
    TM.TASK_CREATOR,
    TM.CREATED_DATE,
    ASSIGNEE.FIRST_NAME,
    ASSIGNEE.FIRST_NAME,
    ASSIGNEE.PHONE_NUMBER,
    CREATOR.FIRST_NAME,
    CREATOR.FIRST_NAME,
    CREATOR.PHONE_NUMBER
FROM 
    TASK_MASTER AS TM 
    INNER JOIN USER_MASTER AS ASSIGNEE 
        ON TM.TASK_ASSIGNEE_ID=ASSIGNEE.USER_ID  
    INNER JOIN USER_MASTER AS CREATOR 
        ON TM.TASK_CREATOR_ID=CREATOR.USER_ID 
where 
    TASK_ID='1'
```

Answer (score 0):

In your join condition you are stipulating that the Assignee and creator must be the same as the User ID. In your example table both tasks to not have the same assignee or creator. So you will get nothing back

Answer (score 0):

Put only 1 cond in Joining 2 tables. Somthing like this:-

```
SELECT 
TM.TASK_ASSIGNEE,
TM.TASK_CREATOR,
TM.CREATED_DATE,
UM.FIRST_NAME,
UM.FIRST_NAME,
UM.PHONE_NUMBER
FROM 
TASK_MASTER TM 
INNER JOIN USER_MASTER UM 
    ON TM.TASK_ASSIGNEE_ID=UM.USER_ID  
WHERE 
TASK_ID='1';
```

This Might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Your query tries to find out if there is a task creator who created a task for himself, you need to add one more join to complete this task:

```
select 
    TM.TASK_CREATOR,
    UM1.FIRST_NAME as creator_first_name,
    UM1.PHONE_NUMBER as creator_phone_number,
    TM.TASK_ASSIGNEE,
    UM2.FIRST_NAME as assignee_first_name,
    UM2.PHONE_NUMBER as assignee_phone_number,
    TM.CREATED_DATE,
FROM 
    TASK_MASTER TM 
    INNER JOIN USER_MASTER UM1 
        ON TM.TASK_CREATOR_ID=UM1.USER_ID 
    INNER JOIN USER_MASTER UM2 
        ON TM.TASK_ASSIGNEE_ID=UM1.USER_ID 
where 
    TASK_ID='1'
```